# WCF web service with exposed stored procedures through ADO entity returns different data results

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, procedure

I have an extremely simple stored procedure returning 2 columns, 1 row of data.

```
SELECT client_id, client_code
FROM wv.client_identifiers
WHERE (client_code = @client_code) 
  AND (version = 0) 
  AND (facility_id = @facility_id) 
  AND (is_active = 1) 
  AND (client_version = 0)
```

It's impossible for this table to have duplicates. When testing this procedure in our web projects for the past 2 years it's worked as intended. Works fine in SSMS as well as Visual Studio server explorer. Problem comes in when we ad this to the WCF service project into ADO.NET Entity Framework.

It sees this fine, creates the functions fine, complex types fine etc etc. I can call this fine from the WPF project fine however, the data returned is not consistent if at all correct.

I have 3 rows for example.

```
client_id client_code 
1001       1252
1002       6655
1003       123
1004       111
1005       5522
```

If I hit the above mentioned procedure through service with parameters it returns bad results.

```
using(var context = new service.MyService())
{
   var Clients = context.GetClientIDFromClient_Code(facility_id, true, client_code)

   foreach(var client in Clients)
   {
     int ClientID = client.client_id;
   }
```

- If I pass in the parameter value of 5522 I get null results.
- If I pass in the parameter value of 123 I get the results for `client_id 1004` and `code` of 111.
- If I pass in the parameter value of 1252 I get the results for `client_id 1004` and code of 111.
- If I pass in ANYTHING starting with `1` followed by whatever I get the same result.
- If I enter ANYTHING that does not start with 1 but is in the DB and should return I get null.

Not sure WHY the WCF is causing the hangup. I can throw this into a linq to sql classes database file and it works fine. I have tried calling this many different ways, tried returning just a single column or single value, I've tried just about everything out there. Not sure if it's doing it on all procedures similar to this one but if I had to guess it would be.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you run SQL profiler while running the WCF call?

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the table? It almost sounds as if your columns - although storing numerical values - are of some string type.